# Websites about programming languages like vimgolf?

Tags: vim

I am a strong vim enthusiast. Recently, I discovered fantastic website about my editor - [VimGolf.com](http://vimgolf.com). I think there is no need to explain how it works. I found out that playing VimGolf is a very efficient way to learn vim.

Because of this, I'm wondering is there any website using similar concept but focused on any programming language (preferably Java, TypeScript, JavaScript or Python) or algorithms? It would be a great way to learn. Of course, I am aware that the whole concept would be different - for example users will get constant amount points for completing some exercise, unlike in VimGolf, where amount of points vary.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codegolf.com/competition/browse
http://www.amebopost.com/contests.php